WebView shows incorrect locale-specific URL on app launch after changing language
I'm working on an Android app that uses a WebView to display locale-specific URLs. When a user changes the device language (for example, from English to Spanish) and relaunches the app, the WebView loads the English URL instead of the Spanish one on the first load.
Here's the sequence to reproduce the issue:
Change the device language (e.g., from English to Spanish).
Kill the app and relaunch it.
Click on InfoButton which launches InfoFragment containing the WebView.
The WebView loads the English version of the URL, not the Spanish one.
Go back and re-enter the fragment - loads the correct Spanish URL.
I've verified that:
The correct (Spanish) URL is being passed to the WebView on both attempts.
I’ve tried setting cacheMode to LOAD_NO_CACHE and clearCache(true), but the issue persists.
I even appended a unique timestamp to the URL to force a fresh load, but it doesn’t solve the problem on the first try.
I have tried clearing cache, enabling cache, enabling domStorage etc. nothing works.
